# PewDiePie's Tuber Simulator won't let me link my account/login. Why?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

So, I just got a new phone and wanted to use the app on it. I looked up how to use the same account, followed the steps (start a new game, click on "link account", and follow the steps), but it did not work. It said that there was no account linked to my Google Play account and when I tried to go onto the game on my old phone, it told me that there was a "Time Dilation Detected".
Should I just not play the game or is there something I can do to play on my original account?

(I don't know if it's relevant, but I have an Oppo F1s)

Answer (score -3):

It means you cheated so it logged you out just change your time back to normal and you can log in